# How can I use Google Sheets Apps Script to clear cells if I uncheck a tick box?

Tags: datetime, google-sheets, checkbox

Not a programmer so I'm begging for a little help.  I have a very simple spreadsheet with certain columns that have tick boxes and adjacent empty columns. My code at this point allows that if the box is checked, the current date and time will be populated in the next cell in the adjacent column. (The code works on all the sheets in the workbook.) I need to know what to add or tweak so that if the box is UNchecked, the neighboring cell will switch back to empty.  Thanks in advance!

```
function onEdit() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var r = s.getActiveCell();
if( r.getColumn() == 2 ) { 
var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) 
nextCell.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm");
}

if( r.getColumn() == 4 ) { 
var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) 
nextCell.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm");
}

if( r.getColumn() == 8 ) { 
var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) 
nextCell.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm");
}

if( r.getColumn() == 10 ) { 
var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) 
nextCell.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm");
}

if( r.getColumn() == 14 ) { 
var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) 
nextCell.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm");
}

if( r.getColumn() == 16 ) { 
var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) 
nextCell.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm");
}
}
```

Comment: You've got an "if" block that checks the .getColumn() value of the cell that's being edited (to confirm if it's one of the checkboxes).  But then, inside that "if" block, you only check if the adjacent cell is blank and, if so, populate with the date.  You'll just need to add another "if" condition to check the value of the checkbox cell - eg. if (r.getValue() == 0) - then, depending on the value of the checkbox cell, you can then set the value of the adjacent cell accordingly.  (Not entirely sure off the top of my head, but I'd suggest that values would be 1 if ticked, 0 if unticked)

Comment: Have you tried the solution provided below? If not, can you provide more info about your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Google Sheets checkbox cell values are 0 (unticked), 1 (ticked), you'd modify your existing if blocks as follows:

```
if( r.getColumn() == 16 ) { 
    var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
    if (r.getValue() == 1) {
        if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) 
            nextCell.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm");
    } else {
        nextCell.setValue('');
    }
}
```

TIP: you could also consolidate the script a little better by using a switch statement, maybe

```
switch (r.getColumn()) {
    case 2:
    case 4:
    case 8:
    , etc ...
    var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
    if (r.getValue() == 1) {
        if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) 
            nextCell.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm");
    } else {
        nextCell.setValue('');
    }
}
```

Since you're running the same block of code in each case, it makes it easier to just have that code in a single block, and then you only need to make changes once.

p.s. you are a programmer now, by the way!